# access video file information using standard Unix utilities

Tags: linux, bash, unix, metadata, resolution

I want to access video file information (specifically, the video horizontal and vertical dimensions) in the Bash terminal of Scientific Linux on a system over which I do not have root privileges. The setup is conservative and does not feature the modern utilities, such as `exiftool` and `avprobe`, that would be used to do this. What would be a way of accessing this information using standard Unix utilities or some other means likely to work on a conservative Linux setup? To be specific, I am looking for something such as the following:

```
<utility> video1.mp4
1280x720
```

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: What kind of input video formats are you expecting?

Comment: MP4 and OGG files are likely to be the overwhelming majority (though f4v may appear sometimes).

Comment: That's going to be tough. A single format you might have gotten away with examining the format and reading bytes. However, another option: you don't need root privileges to get an executable there if it doesn't depend on libraries, you just have to upload it once your know on what kind of system you are, or you may even build the tool from source, you normally don't special privileges for that. It seems the sanest way to avoid re-implementing those tools from scratch, by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to build and run typical open source software from source without root

Even if you don't have root, provided that:

1. you can at least use the compiler and related tools
2. you can download source code
3. you don't need too many strange libraries

then download the source code for your tool of choice and install it into `$HOME/opt/somedir`.

For example, for `avprobe` you could probably download the last stable source release, then build it like this:

```
tar xzf libav.....gz
cd libav.....
./configure --prefix=$HOME/opt/libav
make
make install
```

then run it as

```
$HOME/opt/libav/bin/avprobe
```

You may or may not need to tweak the value of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or various other things.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It appears this is the most balanced way of  making these capabilities available.